# install Hebrew Font matlab

Tags: windows, matlab, unicode, operating-system, hebrew

I am looking for a way to install hebrew fonts in my matlab (R2009b,windows 7). I am not looking for solution to display or read hebrew charecters, but a way to be able to work with hebrew like in english letters (for strings purpusese). the problem that got me here is that I have sound files that their name is in hebrew and I need to read them from matlab. but when I am trying to read the list of files (using ls) I get question marks where the hebrew letters were.

Comment: I don't think that Matlab is the problem here. Matlab merely reflects what the OS does. Try to run 'dir' command at command prompt, you will see the same question marks.

Comment: you are right that when doing dir I am getting the same result. my os supports hebrew (I can see the file names in windows, I also work a lot in hebrew). i am sure that there is a way that would allow me to see the file names from matlab as well

Comment: I get the same thing when using os.listdir(path) in pyhto. so I guess it is something to do with the os. I realize it is not a programming problem. but it would help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The command [listfonts](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/listfonts.html) will list all available system fonts. If no Hebrew font appears in the list, then you'll have to install one at the OS level, such as [AdobeHebrew](https://store2.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-NL&event=displayFont&code=AHEQ10012000) (alternatively, Google "free hebrew fonts").

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the font you're using in Matlab simply doesn't have the Hebrew font glyphs ("characters"). So the missing characters are substituted with '?'. You can "link" a font to another in the GDI by editing the Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink`.

For example: Let's assume your copy of Matlab is using the font Consolas, and you want it to use the font Miriam for glyphs that don't exist in Consolas. To get that to happen, you need to add a String value to the Registry key above. The name of the string must be `Consolas` and it should have a value of `mriamc.ttf`. That tells the Windows GDI to render missing glyphs in the font named "Consolas" using the font in the file "mriamc.ttf".